# Unable to embed google groups to a webpage (not responsive)

Tags: css, html, jekyll, google-groups

I managed to embed my google groups page on to my website [**phisyks-forum**](http://phisyks.github.io/forum.html).

Its great when viewing on a large screen but when viewed on a mobile device it **doesn't re-size** itself.

***I used the iframe code given by google on my groups settings page***. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no responsive code for the google group, add below code

```
.b1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

in css instead of

```
.b1 {
    width: 48px;
    height: 30px;
    }
```

HTML code :

```
<div class="b1"><div class="iQa IY"><span id="aggregateCount"     
class="B8">2</span></div></div>
```

Comment: thanks but i managed to do it by changing width to 100% in the iframe itself, without any CSS or Jquery